# How many class model need to create for get the data of MUSIXMATCH API in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, class, musixmatch

{'message': {'body': {'artist_list': [{'artist': {'artist_alias_list': [],
'artist_comment': '',
'artist_country': '',
'artist_credits': {'artist_list': []},
'artist_edit_url': None,
'artist_id': 26575484.0,
'artist_mbid': None,
'artist_name': 'Illenium',
'artist_name_translation_list': [],
'artist_rating': 55.0, .........

Comment: You can do this online https://quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to generate model classes.